# Remove a right border from Advanced News Ticker

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have installed and customized the JQuery Advanced News Ticker on my website. There is one problem, a right border, that I have not been able to make disappear.  Here is the website (it still needs A LOT of work) so you can see what I am talking about.

http://ccrogers.com/stage/cbk/

It is just below the promotional banner.

Here is the .js file

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            //Quotes rotator
            var divs = $('.cbp-qtcontent');

            function fade() {
                var current = $('.current');
                var currentIndex = divs.index(current),
                    nextIndex = currentIndex + 1;

                if (nextIndex >= divs.length) {
                    nextIndex = 0;
                }

                var next = divs.eq(nextIndex);

                next.stop().fadeIn(1500, function() {
                    $(this).addClass('current');
                });

                current.stop().fadeOut(1500, function() {
                    $(this).removeClass('current');
                    _startProgress()
                    setTimeout(fade, 8000);
                });
            }

            function _startProgress(){
                $(".cbp-qtprogress").removeAttr('style');
                $(".cbp-qtprogress").animate({
                    width:"800px",
                } , 8000);
            }

            _startProgress()
            setTimeout(fade, 8000);
        });
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36251023-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'jqueryscript.net']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

And here is the .css file

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'fontawesome';
src: url('../fonts/fontawesome.eot');
src: url('../fonts/fontawesome.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),  url('../fonts/fontawesome.svg#fontawesome') format('svg'),  url('../fonts/fontawesome.woff') format('woff'),  url('../fonts/fontawesome.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}

body {
font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
color: #47a3da;

}

.main {
width: 800px;
margin:20px auto;

}

.cbp-qtrotator {
width: 800px;
height: 180px;
position: relative;
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding-top: 11px;

}

.cbp-qtcontent {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
position: absolute;
min-height: 100px;
top: 0;
z-index: 2;
display: none;

}

.cbp-qtrotator .cbp-qtcontent.current {
display: block;

}

.cbp-qtrotator blockquote {
margin: 25px 0 0 70px;
padding: 0;

}

.cbp-qtrotator blockquote p {
font-size: 1.25em;
color: #888;
font-weight: 300;
margin: 0 .4em 0 10em;

}

.cbp-qtrotator blockquote footer {
font-size: 1em;
color: #888;
margin:0 0 0 15em;

}

.cbp-qtrotator blockquote footer:before {
content: 'â€• ';

}

.cbp-qtrotator .cbp-qtcontent img {
float: left;
margin: 20px 0 0 0;

}

.cbp-qtprogress {
position: absolute;
background: #47a3da;
height: 1px;
width: 0%;
z-index: 1000;

}
```

Do you need anything else to help me?

I appreciate everyone at StackFlow.  Ya'll have been such a help to this old slow brain!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the CSS:

```
#cbp-qtrotator > div.cbp-qtcontent.current > blockquote{
     border-right: none;
}
```

This will remove the border which is being currently set in `base.css` thusly:

```
blockquote {
 margin: 0 0 0px; 
 padding: 0; 
 border-right: 1px solid #796172; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you again SW4!  What about removing the opacity from just the ticker?  Or do I need to open another question for this one?

Answer (score 0):

The border exists in the blockquote tag.

You can remove this by changing the blockquote css on your tag inline or adding a line to your css.

inline

```
<blockquote style="border:0px;"> ... </blockquote>
```

External CSS Style Sheet

```
blockquote{
    border:0px;
}
```

---

In future to find these we glitches or more about your code, use code-inspector in your browser [F12] and on the right column, you will be able to see all the CSS applied to the selected element.

Comment: Anytime Mr Free-Willy!